# wp_enqueue_script jQuery best practice

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

Trying to setup my first **Wordpress** Theme.
I've a script to calculate the `margin-top` of my content section.
When I put the code below direct in my `<head>` it works fine

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        var height = $('#main-header').height();
        $('#main-content').css({
            'margin-top': height
        });
    }).trigger('load');
</script>
```

Now as I'm learning I want to learn to do the things correct. So....
In my `functions.php` I've added

```
function my_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts-style', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300');
    wp_enqueue_script('fixed-header', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/fixedheader.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('height-script', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/content_height.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_scripts' );
```

Than in my `js` folder I've added the file `content_height.js`

The file `content_height.js` looks like....

```
$(window).load(function() {
   var height = $('#main-header').height();
   $('#main-content').css({
      'margin-top': height
   });
}).trigger('load');
```

But now my script isn't working. 
What am I doing wrong or what did I miss.

May I ask to please explain your answer as I'm learning. Thank you.

Comment: @Manish Patel jQuery is already enqueued as a dependency of `height-script`, which is the correct way to do it. 
There's a typo in `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_customscripts' );`, the callback parameter must have the same name as the callback function. Does `fixedheader.js` not use jQuery? Also, you should look into your browser's console to see any possible javascript errors.

Comment: this was a typo, the callback parameter and the callback function are the same. my_custom_script

Comment: And no javascript errors in het browsers console

Comment: Check the network tab of your browsers console to see if the scripts are loaded at all.

Comment: No, doesn't get loaded...why?

Comment: Try to replace the version parameter `null` with `false`. I had issues with scripts not loading when they had no version number attached.

Comment: No, still not loading

Comment: Do I need to add something to my content_height.js file?

Comment: Check your path twice whether it is pointing to the actual file: `get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/content_height.js`

Comment: It's correct. I think the issue is with the jQuery. I've added an other file and it doesn't get loaded neither

Comment: Then you need to start debugging at the very beginning and see whether the function `my_custom_scripts` actually gets called. Also if you're on Linux, check file permissions.

Comment: Do you know how I need to convert my content-height.js file to a normal javascript file? I don't have issues with javascript, just jquery

Comment: I've just added <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> to my <head> and than it works.....I needed to remove , array('jquery'), null, true